# Memory not released, even as object ref count 0

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory-management, cpython

In the following code snippet, `x` is no longer defined however the memory it took has not been released. Why?

```
import psutil
import os
def memtest():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    x = (process.memory_info().rss)/10**6
    return float(x)

def myfunc():
    x = [2]*10**7
    return 0

print(memtest())
myfunc()
print(memtest())
```

Output:

```
9.519104
89.546752
```

Based on the idea of reference counting, `x` has its reference count increase by 1 when it is defined in the local scope of the `myfunc`, as soon as we leave that scope, it has its reference count decrease by 1 and so the memory associated with that object should have been freed. Why is this not the case?

EDIT:

Even after running `del x` the memory is not freed. Why?

```
import psutil
import os
def memtest():
    process = psutil.Process(os.getpid())
    x = (process.memory_info().rss)/10**6
    return float(x)

def myfunc():
    x = [2]*10**7
    del x
    return 0

print(memtest())
myfunc()
print(memtest())
```

Output

```
9.629696
89.657344
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allocators don't always release memory back to the OS; they'll hang on to it to satisfy future allocations without needing to rerequest memory from the OS (much more expensive than partitioning existing allocations). Try calling your function a few times in a row; if the memory usage *keeps* increasing, okay, maybe there is a problem, but in most cases, most of the memory used in the future comes from what you released earlier.

To be clear, `del` does nothing of use in your code. All it does is release the current reference to the `list` bound to `x`. Since `x` is a purely local variable that you don't return, that reference would be released at the moment you `return` anyway. `del` of bare names is rarely useful (outside of rare cases involving temporaries at global scope that you want to get rid of after they've been used in some other global initialization), since the `del`ed name would usually disappear in short order anyway.

Comment: Ok running the code again, Im seeing that there is no memory leak present! Just checking, can that memory be used to store any type of data, or just the same kind (for example another list containing integers ONLY)? I.e if I were to continue writing code and were to define a variable y in the global scope, `y= ['hi']*10**3`, would it use part of the memory originally used by x, or a completely separate chunk from the OS?

Comment: @credtz: There are free lists scattered all over CPython that can only be used for that type, but those free lists are storing objects that max out at well under 1 KB (typically under 200 B). For large allocations like the one you're making, they can theoretically be reused for anything. In practice, CPython maintains a separation between small and large allocations, so it probably won't get reused for anything under the small object allocator limit, just for big stuff, but it could be a big `set` or `bytes` just as easily as a big `list` (contents don't matter; `int` or `str`, no difference).